# .xib Called Inside ViewController Does not Recognize Touch Events

Tags: ios, swift, nib

Inside a `UIViewController`, I call a .xib file and present it over the current UIView.

```
// initiate the pop up ad view and display it
let popUpAdView = PopUpAdViewController(nibName: "PopUpAdView", bundle: nil)
popUpAdView.displayIntoSuperView(view)
```

There is a button inside that .xib file that should remove itself from the screen when it's touched. However it doesn't perform so.

What exactly am I missing?

```
class PopUpAdViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var popUpAdView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var closeButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  // adjust the view size from the device's screen size
  let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
  view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, screenSize.width, screenSize.height-64)

  // cosmetically adjust the view itself
  view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6)
  view.userInteractionEnabled = true
  closeButton.userInteractionEnabled = true

  // style the pop up ad view
  popUpAdView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
  popUpAdView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
  popUpAdView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)

  closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeOutOfSuperView), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}

func displayIntoSuperView(superView: UIView!) {
  superView.addSubview(self.view)

  // define the initial cosmetical values of the items
  popUpAdView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.3, 0.3)
  popUpAdView.alpha = 0.0
  closeButton.alpha = 0.0

  // animate...
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
    self.popUpAdView.alpha = 1.0
    self.popUpAdView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
  }) { (Bool) in
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 1.5, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
      self.closeButton.alpha = 1.0
      }, completion: { (Bool) in

    })
  }
}

func removeOutOfSuperView() {
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
    self.closeButton.alpha = 0.0
    self.popUpAdView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1)
  }) { (finished) in
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
      self.view.alpha = 0.0
      self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }, completion: nil)
  }
}

@IBAction func closePopUpAdView(sender: AnyObject) {
  print("Closing the pop up ad...")
  removeOutOfSuperView()
}
}
```

**Update**

.xib structureL:

[image]

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var closeButton: UIButton!

your button property has weak reference, thought it lost its target.

Please set your button refrence as strong.

Comment: I removed the `weak` keyword and still unable to touch the button.

Comment: try bringSubViewToFront for button after adding target.

Comment: button is on  scrollview？

Comment: @wg_hjl please see the update to the question

Comment: you set closebtn alpha？this may course can not be click

Comment: @wg_hjl Initially I didn't had the alpha change and the button was still not working. In the mean time, I added some animation using the alpha change just to make it a little fancy.

Comment: give colsebtn a line to action ，not a property IBoutlet ，try removeOutOfSuperView whether called，or btn added，try this

Comment: @wg_hjl not exactly sure but if you ask me to check out if `removeOutOfSuperView` method is working or not then it is. I checked it with the animation's completion handler that when animation finished, call `removeOutOfSuperView`.